# Why the VBA Code does not work in Excel 2016?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I can not write any VBA code in my Excel 2016 (under win 10)
I go to the developer menu and I choose Visual Basic button. then I choose a sheet and I do a double click on it. then Excel goes to closing and restarts itself.
Wath happen?
Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  This question has received a close vote as "too broad".  That's because it's the kind of problem that might be caused by a range of specific or random problems, and there isn't enough diagnostic detail in the question for any reader to be able to definitively answer.  It also means that any specific answer might be unlikely to be the solution for most people given the range of possibilities.  Kudos for finding your own solution (good answer and I upvoted it).  But if the question ends up being closed, just wanted you to understand why.  Keep contributing.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to this issue! ... I did a click on the **"Reference ..."** in VBA Developer in Excel and I get this message: **Unrecognised Project Language** then I went to the **Regional Setting** and I cleaned up (uncheck) the Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 ... Now the VBA work correctly.